# jQuery get() element some problems

Tags: jquery

I'm tring to get first button element and add class to it. However it's not working....

**JavaScript**

```
var a = $('button').get(0);
a.addClass('yellow');
```

**HTML**

```
<button>click</button>
<button>click</button>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tuxsanov/yDRLh/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use eq method instead of get.

eq(i), where i is index of selected element. so in your scenario use i=0

'eq' method return matched jquery object while 'get' will return the matched dom element so if you want to edit some property using "get" you have to select the element again using jquery or plain javascript.

so

```
var a=$('button').get(0);   // get the dom element button, no object
   $(a).addClass('yellow');     // select element and then add property
```

Comment: OP wants to achieve it using ``get()``

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like this using [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/):

```
var a = $('button:first');
```

Here is using `get()`

```
var a = $('button').get(0);

$(a).addClass('yellow');
```

Comment: i wanted to use get()

Comment: is there any method to select element using ``get()`` ??

Comment: you were not applying it with ``$(a)``